# Can I see the backlog as a treeview when filtering out done items on Azure Boards?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-boards

I'm using the [basic work item process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=azure-devops) in Azure DevOps.

If I look at my backlog without any filters, then it shows me a hierarchy, with epics as the top-level items, then issues and then work items.

If I filter this to only show items that are to do or doing, it shows them as a flat list, not a hierarchy.

Is there any way to see the items as a hierarchy, but filter out done items?

**Update following Shayki Abramczyk's comment**

The options button doesn't include an option to show parents...

[image]

Comment: near the "filter" icon you have "options" button, click there and move the "parents" to ON.

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Thanks, but I don't have a "parents" option. Please see my updated question. Thanks, any other ideas?

Comment: Near the "Options" button in the left choose "Backlog items"

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Sorry, you lost me. To the left of the options button I have a dropdown where you can choose Epics or Issues. Don't have anything to the left of that until you get to the "New work item" / "View as board" and "Column options" links over on the left. Where did mean? Can't see anywhere to choose "Backlog items." Thanks again

Comment: I mean to this drop-down list. if you move to issues the "Parents" option exist?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes, but then I don't see the epics (and I had parents on anyway). Although it seems a bit painful, jessehouwing's answer did it. Thanks again for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to the Work Item Query tab and create a work item query. Configure it to Tree view and let it follow the parent/child relation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can filter on the top level (top part of the query editor) and the lower levels (bottom part of the query editor). Use the `State in` filter to select multiple states. You can't multi-select them in the UI, so typing is required:

[image]

PS: The `,` is the list separator in most languages, but sometimes you need to use `;`.

If you want to see parents when ANY child leaf is still open, set the `Filter: Match top-level items first` to `Filter: Match child-level items first`.

To specify the order, add the `Backlog Priority` field to the query and use the table header to sort by it:

[image]

Or use the Sorting option in the "Choose Columns" fly-out:

[image]

Note: The exact field name differs per Process template. Backlog Priority is for the Scrum Template, Stackrank for CMMI and Agile and Basic:

[image]

An easy way to get started is to take the board view closest to what you want and save it as a work item query.

[image]

Comment: This used to be the only way until 2015 or so :).

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that using this method, I can't reorder items, and the ordering I had set when viewing the backlog is ignored. Anything I can do about that? The ordering was useful for putting the high-priority items at the top

Comment: Yeah ordering only works on the backlog pages. Check out the 'epics' item on the filter dialog and make sure all levels are selected.

Comment: You can order the query through the query settings. There is a hidden field that keeps the backlog order.

Comment: Thanks again, shame I can't give you another vote :)

Comment: No matter! Thanks for your gratitude. It's a lot more than others tend to give.